# Which article (por/para) should I use to express that I go to the drugstore for medicine？

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

1. Voy a la farmacia por medicina.
2. Voy a la farmacia para medicina.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wimi's answer is indeed correct. Perhaps there is some confusion on the part of OP around the use of "para". The preposition "para" could be used with an infinitive:

- Voy a la farmacia **para comprar** medicina.

The preposition "para" can be followed by nouns but not in the case at issue, for example:

- Este dinero es **para medicina**. (This money is for medicine, i.e. to be spent on medicine.)

With "ir", meaning "go and get", the preposition "por" is required.

Comment: Aha! Got it ! So, is there any terminology or definition to define the second circumstance ? By the way,your edition made the question clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As explained by [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/ir-por-agua-o-ir-por-agua), "going to fetch something" is usually translated as "ir a por algo" in Spain and as "ir por algo" in Latin America. So

> Voy a la farmacia a por medicina

and

> Voy a la farmacia por medicina

are both correct.

Comment: Hi,wimi ! I am sorry but you misunderstood my problem.

Answer (score 1):

From "Complete Spanish Grammar, 3rd Edition" by McGraw Hill Education:

**Para** indicates:

- *purpose* of an action, goal, event or object, equivalent to "in order to"
- *comparison* contrasting one idea, person, object or situation to others in the same group or category
- *deadlines* equivalent to *"for"*, *"by"*, or *"on"* with a time indicator.
- *destination* being a place or a person
- note that some expressions ending with *para* cannot be followed by a noun.

**Por** indicates:

- *exchange* as *"in exchange for"* in bartering, commerce, etc
- *movement* either through a space or area or as *"by means of"*
- *duration* with an indication of how long in time
- *expressions of time*, related to morning, night, etc
- *causality* as *"because of"*
- equivalent to *per*
- some more idiomatic expressions

To answer your question:

**por** is correct, it can be interpreted that you are going to the pharmacy *because of* the need for medicine.

To use **para**, You would rephrase to indicate the pharmacy as your destination (*Estoy saliendo para la farmacia*) or the purpose of going there (*Voy a la farmacia para comprar medicamentos*).

Comment: "ir para" cannot be followed by a noun in Spanish, and "medicina" is a noun.

Comment: Actually you are right @Gustavson. I have corrected my answer, please let me know if I still have any mistakes.